# Multiple lateral view and explode in hive produce rows duplication

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, explode

I am working with 4 columns

| Ref_No | Currency | Amount | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EBDR001 | usd^usd^usd^usd^ | 240^300^210^500^ | DBC^ODA^ICA^DRA |

I Want data in this format

| Ref_No | Currency | Amount | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EBDR001 | usd | 240 | DBC |
| EBDR001 | usd | 300 | ODA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 210 | ICA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 500 | DRA |

The result I am getting

| Ref_No | Currency | Amount | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EBDR001 | usd | 240 | DBC |
| EBDR001 | usd | 240 | DBC |
| EBDR001 | usd | 240 | DBC |
| EBDR001 | usd | 240 | DBC |
| EBDR001 | usd | 300 | ODA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 300 | ODA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 300 | ODA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 300 | ODA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 210 | ICA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 210 | ICA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 210 | ICA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 210 | ICA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 500 | DRA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 500 | DRA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 500 | DRA |
| EBDR001 | usd | 500 | DRA |

Like this there are over thousand of rows with different Ref_No.

The query I am using is

```
select Ref,ccy,amt,tag_1 from table1
lateral view explode(split(ccy,"\\^")) myTable12 as ccy
lateral view explode(split(amt,"\\^")) myTable13 as amt
lateral view explode(split(tag_1 ,"\\^")) myTable14 as tag_1
```

Comment: The question is not MySQL-related - remove wrong tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple lateral view produce Cartesian product.** The solution is to use single lateral view posexplode, split other columns to get arrays, then use position to address other values.

Some columns contain extra `^` delimiter at the end, remove it before splitting.

Demo:

```
with table1 as (--Data example, use your table instead
select 'EBDR001' Ref_No, 'usd^usd^usd^usd^' Currency, '240^300^210^500^' Amount, 'DBC^ODA^ICA^DRA' Tag
)

select Ref_No, 
       c.ccy, 
       split(t1.Amount,"\\^")[c.pos] amt, 
       split(t1.Tag,"\\^")[c.pos]    tag
  from ( --Remove extra delimiter at the end
        select Ref_No, 
               regexp_replace(Currency,'\\^$','') Currency, 
               regexp_replace(Amount,'\\^$','')   Amount,
               regexp_replace(Tag,'\\^$','')      Tag
          from table1
       ) t1
       lateral view posexplode(split(t1.Currency,"\\^")) c as pos, ccy
```

Result:

```
ref_no  c.ccy amt   tag
EBDR001 usd   240   DBC
EBDR001 usd   300   ODA
EBDR001 usd   210   ICA
EBDR001 usd   500   DRA
```

**Possible alternatives:**

You can use posexplode instead of explode in three lateral views and WHERE clause to match positions of three lateral views, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59497463/2700344

Also you can use three CTEs in which you posexplode each array, then LEFT JOIN them with main table ON Ref and Pos, similar solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56244552/2700344.