# URL Params extraction in Hive

Tags: split, hive, url-parameters, query-string

I am trying to extract URL Query parameter from the URL in Hive with the below method.

```
SELECT split(cid.key, '%3d') [1] AS connectionID
    FROM omni 
    LATERAL VIEW explode(str_to_map(parse_url(omni.full_url, 'QUERY'), '&', '=') ) queryparams 
    LATERAL VIEW explode(str_to_map(queryparams.value, '%2')) cid
WHERE queryparams.key = 'tag'
  AND split(cid.key, '%3d') [0] = 'cid'
```

I need to extract value of **cid** from the URL into a new column in the same row.
However, I am getting multiple rows repeated (may be getting cartesian product ? )
For example, one row of CID is repeated for 3-4 rows.
I am new to lateral view, any help on what I am doing wrong is appreciated!

URL Pattern looks like this:

> `https://www.***********ize?response_type=id_token&client_id=******&redirect_uri=*******l/in/228467e4-d9b6-4b04-8a11-45e1cc9f786d&scope=openid&code_challenge=E9M***********JSstw-cM&code_challenge_method=S256&tag=cid%3***********8-e94f97d20ab9%2caid%3d************a-4fb1-b6e5-c65650428a83&state=aHR*****************Z2luT3JSZWdpc3Rlcg%3d%3d#features_section`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lateral view explode(map) produces row for each key-value pair. Explicit syntax is:

```
LATERAL VIEW explode(str_to_map(parse_url(omni.full_url, 'QUERY'), '&', '=') ) p as key, value
```

This produces row for each key= value:

```
tag=cidxxx 
scope=openid
client_id=****** 
and so on...
```

Second lateral can produce more rows: for each row from 1st lateral view it potentially can generate rows and it can be a Cartesian product.

If you just need to extract value of cid from the URL into a new column in the same row, then you can do it without exploding all key-value pairs. If you parsed parameters and converted to map, use map[key] to get value and transform it as necessary.

Extract tag value:

```
SELECT str_to_map(parse_url(omni.full_url, 'QUERY'), '&', '=')['tag']
  FROM omni
```

For your URL example it produces:

```
 'cid%3***********8-e94f97d20ab9%2caid%3d************a-4fb1-b6e5-c65650428a83'
```

You can transform value and extract everything you need from it

`split(str_to_map(parse_url(omni.full_url, 'QUERY'), '&', '=')['tag'],'%3')[1]`

will return

`'***********8-e94f97d20ab9%2caid%3d************a-4fb1-b6e5-c65650428a83'`

And so on...

At least it seems you definitely can do without second lateral view if not without both.

You obfuscated URL and now I do not see how that can be converted to map as in your query, hope you got the idea.

See also about multiple lateral views: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69735508/2700344, but I believe this is not your case, you can do without lateral views with explode at all if you do not need to get many rows.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my question. this works without additional lateral views.